# Eclipse CDT error 193 after executing or starting debug mode

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Im developing a C project in Eclipse Oxygen from June 2017 with CDT Plugin. After some more code changes in my project, my compiled application will not execute any longer or I cant start the debug mode with the recent project executable.

For the execution the following error will be thrown: "make (e=193): Error 193"
For the start of debug mode the error message is:
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Error creating process
C:..\Xy.exe, (error 193).
Error creating process
C:..\Xy.exe, (error 193).

After some reading in forums I do not have found a solution. I investigated the path for spaces and I cleaned and rebuild the project, but nothing changes.

Could somebody help?

Greetings, Nico

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is 4 years and 13 releases behind. There is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I got it! My program requires too much memory, such that the program cannot execute.